# Equivalent to StAX for C

Tags: java, c, xml

I've used the StAX API in Java quite a bit, and find it quite a clean way of dealing with XML files. Is there any equivalent library I could use for performing similar processing in C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/) is a heavily used and documented XML library for C, which provides a SAX API. [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) is another, but in my experience is not as well documented.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Expat pretty extensively - I like it for its simplicity and small footprint.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to C++ then [try LLama](http://llamaxml.berlios.de/)

Answer (score -1):

Expat does StAX

```
 #include "expat.h"`
VRM_parser = XML_ParserCreate("ISO-8859-1");
XML_SetElementHandler(VRM_parser, CbStartTagHandler, CbEndTagHandler);
XML_Parse(VRM_parser, text, strlen(text), 0); // start of XML
XML_Parse(VRM_parser, text, strlen(text), 0); // more XML
XML_Parse(VRM_parser, text, strlen(text), 0); // more XML
XML_Parse(VRM_parser, text, strlen(text), 0); // more XML
XML_Parse(VRM_parser, "", 0, 1); // to finish parsing
```